# Sort numbers by binary 1's count

Tags: code-golf, sorting, bitwise

#### Goal

Write a function or program sort an array of integers in descending order by the number of 1's present in their binary representation.  No secondary sort condition is necessary.

#### Example sorted list

(using 16-bit integers)

```
  Dec                Bin        1's
16375   0011111111110111        13
15342   0011101111101110        11
32425   0111111010101001        10
11746   0010110111100010         8
28436   0000110111110100         8
19944   0100110111101000         8
28943   0000011100011111         8
 3944   0000011111101000         7
15752   0011110110001000         7
  825   0000000011111001         6
21826   0101010101000010         6
```

#### Input

An array of 32-bit integers.

#### Output

An array of the same integers sorted as described.

#### Scoring

This is code golf for the least number of bytes to be selected in one week's time.

Comment: You didn't explicitly mention, but does it need to be in descending order?

Comment: You're right, I missed that.  Everyone else has gone with descending, so we'll stick with that.

Comment: I think the final number (21826) has been converted wrong. according to my Windows calculator, it's 0101 0101 0100 0010, not 0010 1010 1100 0010.

Comment: Thanks for those corrections.  That's weird about 21826 because I used Excel to convert the numbers to binary.  I wonder about the rest now.

Comment: Solution using assembly and popcount instruction?

Comment: Some CPUs have efficient opcodes for doing this, but I suspect assembly language to be a bit too verbose to win code golf. (I think Motorola 68040 had it.)

Comment: Does the sort have to be stable or not?

Comment: Am I allowed to sort the input array in-place? It is a difference of 8 characters for my solution.

Comment: Stability is not required.  I never said the input had to remain unchanged, so in-place sorting is fine.

Comment: formatted test cases please?

Comment: Similar to the [Bittiest number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/216621/15940) challenge

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### J (11)

```
(\:+/"1@#:)
```

This is a function that takes a list:

```
     (\:+/"1@#:) 15342 28943 16375 3944 11746 825 32425 28436 21826 15752 19944
16375 15342 32425 28943 11746 28436 19944 3944 15752 825 21826
```

If you want to give it a name, it costs one extra character:

```
     f=:\:+/"1@#:
     f 15342 28943 16375 3944 11746 825 32425 28436 21826 15752 19944
16375 15342 32425 28943 11746 28436 19944 3944 15752 825 21826
```

Explanation:

- `\:`: downwards sort on
- `+/`: sum of
- `"1`: each row of
- `#:`: binary representation

Comment: @ak82 it's the ASCII version of APL

Comment: @JanDvorak of sorts; there have been quite a few changes: http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/j4apl.htm (see Language section).

Comment: There's also `\:1#.#:` which saves a few bytes.

Answer (score 17):

## JavaScript, 39

**Update:** Now shorter than Ruby.

```
x.sort(q=(x,y)=>!x|-!y||q(x&x-1,y&y-1))
```

**40**

```
x.sort(q=(x,y)=>x&&y?q(x&x-1,y&y-1):x-y)
```

Explanation:

q is a recursive function. If x or y are 0, it returns `x-y` (a negative number if x is zero or a positive number if y is zero). Otherwise it removes the lowest bit (`x&x-1`) from x and y and repeats.

**Previous version (42)**

```
x.sort(q=(x,y)=>x^y&&!x-!y+q(x&x-1,y&y-1))
```

Comment: This is really clever! I'm still trying to wrap my mind around it.

Comment: Shouldn't `~y` work instead of `-!y`?

Comment: @toothbrush The ending condition is that x or y are 0, in which case the expression `!x|-!y` becomes non-zero. `~` doesn't really fit in since it's non-zero for many inputs (including zero)

Comment: Can anyone help me in case a [secondary sorting is required](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/163021/80046), please?

Answer (score 16):

## Ruby 41

```
f=->a{a.sort_by{|n|-n.to_s(2).count(?1)}}
```

Test:

```
a = [28943, 825, 11746, 16375, 32425, 19944, 21826, 15752, 15342, 3944, 28436];
f[a]
=> [16375, 15342, 32425, 11746, 28436, 28943, 19944, 15752, 3944, 21826, 825]
```

Comment: Simple. Understandable. Short. Kudos for this solution.

Answer (score 8):

### Python 3 (44):

```
def f(l):l.sort(lambda n:-bin(n).count('1'))
```

Answer (score 8):

### Common Lisp, 35

[`logcount`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_logcou.htm) returns the number of ‘on’-bits in a number.  For a list `l`, we have:

```
(sort l '> :key 'logcount)
```

```
CL-USER> (sort (list 16375 15342 32425 11746 28436 19944 28943 3944 15752 825 21826) '> :key 'logcount)
;=> (16375 15342 32425 11746 28436 19944 28943 3944 15752 825 21826)
```

As a standalone function, and what I'll base the byte count on:

```
(lambda(l)(sort l'> :key'logcount))
```

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, <del>90</del> <del>77</del> <del>72</del> 67 characters.

Our solution takes an input from the command-line, and prints the number in descending order (67 chars), or ascending (66).

**Descending order**

```python
print(sorted(input().split(),key=lambda x:-bin(int(x)).count("1"))) # 67
```

Thanks to **@daniero**, for the suggestion of using a minus in the 1's count to reverse it, instead of using a slice to reverse the array at the end! This effectively saved 5 characters.

Just for the sake of posting it, the ascending order version (which was the first we made) would take one character less.

**Ascending order**:

```python
print(sorted(input().split(),key=lambda x:bin(int(x)).count("1"))) # 66
```

Thanks to **@Bakuriu** for the *key=lambda x…* suggestion. ;D

Comment: So `0` will always be a part of your output then; That's not correct.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question that prohibits me from inserting a value.

Comment: I do: "An array of *the same integers* sorted as described." ;) Besides, why not just use `raw_input()` and drop some characters?

Comment: @daniero fixed it. Switching to Python 3 (a Python 2 answer was already present, gotta be creative!) allows me to use _input()_, saving two characters (two are to be added because of the brackets required by _print()_).

Comment: You can drop the `[]` inside `sorted`. Also the output of this program is the number of 1s in the numbers in input sorted, but you should output the number you received in input, sorted using the number of `1`s. Something like: `print(sorted(input().split(), key=lambda x:bin(int(x)).count('1')))` would be correct.

Comment: @Bakuriu awesome! Thank you. Your suggestion prints values in ascending order, though, which may or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: You can use `lambda x:-bin(...`  insted of `[::-1]`, sort of like I did :)

Comment: @daniero Clever… StackOverflow teaches you how to do things properly, CodeGolf teaches you the best proper hacks. I'm glad I found this site. ;D -- For a moment I though we could use the fact that binaries contain only 0's and 1's to our advantage (if we sort by ascending order, and by the number of 0's, we get the number with the least 0's (and thus, the most 1's) first) -- but then I recalled that Python doesn't pad binary numbers with 0's…

Comment: The second argument to `sorted` is `key`, so there's no need for `key=` either.

Comment: Question defines input and output as an array.  So it seems there is no need parse input and print output.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript [76 bytes]

```
a.sort(function(x,y){r='..toString(2).split(1).length';return eval(y+r+-x+r)})
```

where `a` is an input array of numbers.

**Test:**

```
[28943,825,11746,16375,32425,19944,21826,15752,15342,3944,28436].sort(function(x, y) {
    r = '..toString(2).split(1).length';
    return eval(y + r + -x + r);
});

[16375, 15342, 32425, 19944, 11746, 28943, 28436, 15752, 3944, 21826, 825]
```

Comment: Could you please tell how the `..` works? My understanding is that if `x = 5` then `eval(x + r)` becomes `eval(5..toString(2).match(/1/g).length)` which is, I suppose, invalid. Thanks.

Comment: @GaurangTandon It is not. As you know, in JS everything except literals is an object. And numbers. So theoretically (and practically) you may get properties or call methods of any non-literal via dot notation, as you do `'string'.length` or `[1,2,3].pop()`. In case of numbers you may do the same but you should keep in mind that after a single dot the parser will look for a fractional part of the number expecting a float value (as in `123.45`). If you use an integer you should "tell" the parser that a fractional part is empty, setting an extra dot before addressing a property: `123..method()`.

Comment: You can save two bytes by stripping the zeros and treating the rest as a decimal number. Replace `match(/1/g).length` with `replace(/0/g,"")`.

Comment: @VisioN Thanks! Learnt a new thing.

Comment: Can anyone help me in case a [secondary sorting is required](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/163021/80046), please?

Comment: ```a.sort(function(x,y){r='..toString(2).match(/1/g).length';return eval(y+r+-x+r)})```

Comment: 69 Bytes `a.sort((x,y)=>{f=z=>z.toString(2).replace(/0/g,"");return f(x)<f(y)})` Correct me if i'm wrong but length isn't needed if you use `<` instead of `-`

Comment: [75](https://tio.run/##HcjPCsIgHADgV@mo4Az/ba4YPUTH6CDLzBAd@ltsRM9uq8t3@J7mZcqY/QRNTDdbzXDhupeCaK4IY51sCWtFp4jg8jd9LyXhTPPtVaf4ppCciH9rKdrrcUyxpGBpSA5VQ0vKgNxwn@MIPkW0kBW/s4U5xx3bryeHVtw4tODDQiGdIfvoEMe0TMEDYpgGGx08Prji@gU) using same formula and version

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica 30

```
SortBy[#,-DigitCount[#,2,1]&]&
```

Usage:

```
SortBy[#,-DigitCount[#,2,1]&]&@
                           {19944,11746,15342,21826,825,28943,32425,16375,28436,3944,15752}
```

> {16375, 15342, 32425, 11746, 19944, 28436, 28943, 3944, 15752, 825, 
>   21826}

Answer (score 6):

## k [15 Chars]

```
{x@|<+/'0b\:'x}
```

#### Example 1

```
{x@|<+/'0b\:'x}19944, 11746, 15342, 21826, 825, 28943, 32425, 16375, 28436, 3944, 15752

16375 15342 32425 28436 28943 11746 19944 15752 3944 825 21826
```

#### Example 2 (all numbers are 2^n -1)

```
{x@|<{+/0b\:x}'x}3 7 15 31 63 127

127 63 31 15 7 3
```

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8 - <s>87/113</s> <s>81/111</s> <s>60/80</s> 60/74/48 characters

This is not a complete java program, it is just a function (a method, to be exact).

It assumes that `java.util.List` and `java.lang.Long.bitCount` are imported, and has 60 characters:

```java
void s(List<Long>a){a.sort((x,y)->bitCount(x)-bitCount(y));}
```

If no pre-imported stuff are allowed, here it is with 74 characters:

```java
void s(java.util.List<Long>a){a.sort((x,y)->x.bitCount(x)-x.bitCount(y));}
```

Add more 7 characters if it would be required that it should be `static`.

[4 years later] Or if you prefer, it could be a lambda (thanks @KevinCruijssen for the suggestion), with 48 bytes:

```java
a->{a.sort((x,y)->x.bitCount(x)-x.bitCount(y));}
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't do `Integer.bitCount(x)<Integer.bitCount(y)?-1:1;`? Do you need the `-1,0,1` behavior?

Comment: Also, is it possible to replace the `<Integer>` with space?

Comment: You can also use `Long`, that save some space :)

Comment: Also   `a.sort((x,y)->Long.bitCount(x)-Long.bitCount(y));`

Comment: @Quincunx comparator needs to return 0 when bitcounts are the same (by contract)

Comment: @Quincunx. Yes, I needed the `-1,0,1` behaviour, but by using `-` as suggested by RobAu, it gets smaller. And really need the `<Long>` (was `<Integer>`). Otherwise I screw the compiler type inference and get a compile error.

Comment: @RobAu Thanks, I should have seen those obvious shortcuts.

Comment: Realistically, this is a function because it doesn't leverage the `this` reference or any of `this`'s variables. So while technically a method because it -could-, it doesn't; I would personally call this a function. (This is reinforced by the fact that you could, as you state, make it static. Static method === function.)

Comment: I have a complete 150 char java 8 solution. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22064/7981

Comment: I know it's been 4 years, but you can golf `Long.bitCount` to `x.bitCount` in your version without pre-imported stuff (not sure how it was four years ago, but imports are counted towards the byte-count these days). Also, since you've specified Java 8, you can change `void s(java.util.List<Long>a)` to `a->`. [Try it online - **48 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/y73zpwu4) Nice answer though, +1 from me.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I don't remember this puzzle, since as you already said, it was 4 years since then. However, I'm not sure if a lambda expression with a inferred parameter type depending on an ommited context would be acceptable. Anyway, I added it to the answer, thanks.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Well, it is acceptable these days, but I also don't know about four years ago when this challenge was posted. Btw, in the 80-byte version you can still golf `Long.bitCount` to `x.bitCount`, since you've already specified `x` is a Long in the `java.util.List<Long>a` parameter.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks. I'm so used that using a variable instance to call a static method is a bad practice that I ever forgot that the compiler accepts that.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica 39

`IntegerDigits[#,2]` converts a base 10 number to list of 1's and 0's.

`Tr` sums the digits.

```
f@n_:=SortBy[n,-Tr@IntegerDigits[#,2]&]
```

**Test Case**

```
f[{19944, 11746, 15342, 21826, 825, 28943, 32425, 16375, 28436, 3944, 15752}]
```

> {16375, 15342, 32425, 11746, 19944, 28436, 28943, 3944, 15752, 825, 21826}

Comment: I've grown fond of that (ab?)use of Tr[] in golfing code.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2.x - 65 characters (bytes)

```
print sorted(input(),key=lambda x:-sum(int(d)for d in bin(x)[2:]))
```

That's actually 66 characters, 65 if we make it a function (then you need something to call it which is lamer to present).

```
f=lambda a:sorted(a,key=lambda x:-sum(int(d)for d in bin(x)[2:]))
```

Demo in Bash/CMD:

```
echo [16, 10, 7, 255, 65536, 5] | python -c "print sorted(input(),key=lambda x:-sum(int(d)for d in bin(x)[2:]))"
```

Comment: you can change `sum(int(d)for d in bin(x)[2:])` to `sum(map(int,bin(x)[2:]))`

Comment: or even: `print sorted(input(),key=lambda x:-bin(x).count('1'))`

Answer (score 4):

## Matlab, 34

Input in 'a'

```
[~,i]=sort(-sum(dec2bin(a)'));a(i)
```

Works for nonnegative numbers.

Answer (score 4):

### **C - 85 bytes (<del>108</del> 106 bytes)**

Portable version on GCC/Clang/wherever `__builtin_popcount` is available (106 bytes):

```
#define p-__builtin_popcount(
c(int*a,int*b){return p*b)-p*a);}
void s(int*n,int l){qsort(n,l,sizeof l,c);}
```

Ultra-condensed, non-portable, barely functional MSVC-only version (85 bytes):

```
#define p __popcnt
c(int*a,int*b){return p(*b)-p(*a);}
s(int*n,int l){qsort(n,l,4,c);}         /* or 8 as needed */
```

---

- First newline included in byte count because of the `#define`, the others are not necessary.
- Function to call is `s(array, length)` according to specifications.
- Can hardcode the `sizeof` in  the portable version to save another 7 characters, like a few  other C answers did. I'm not sure which one is worth the most in terms of length-usability ratio, you decide.

Comment: `sizeof l` saves a byte. The horribly ugly `#define p-__builtin_popcount(` can help save another one.

Comment: @ugoren Thanks for the tips! The preprocessor one is such a hack, I had no idea such a thing was possible. Sadly it does not work on MSVC, but every byte counts!

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##pY1NCsIwGET3OUUJCIn9xNZqf4jewBuoi5g2JVjb2kQollzdGBFXLt0Nw3szYlEL4ZwmLTRUtWbesummu8G8C1jDHh/H7JxHUibHMU6/SSRltCowZdZduWoJnZCXA3447aYYVpB4dQMpZJBDAXFkGZLdQN6M2kVMbbV6VJ0M@PIT5pypMPQr/eAZSfCsDDDwgzpRhizq70YT7O@QJhx@XPrfunVPIRtea7d4VGMltOHi8gI "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## PowerShell v3, <s>61</s> <s>58</s> 53

```
$args|sort{while($_){if($_-band1){1};$_=$_-shr1}}-des
```

The ScriptBlock for the `Sort-Object` cmdlet returns an array of 1's for each 1 in the binary representation of the number. `Sort-Object` sorts the list based on the length of the array returned for each number.

To execute:

```
script.ps1 15342 28943 16375 3944 11746 825 32425 28436 21826 15752 19944
```

Comment: it's work. How it work? How the magic '.' comes to 'based on the length of the array'?

Comment: The '.' executes the scriptblock that comes after it. The sort command sorts based on the output of the outer scriptblock. I realize now that the inner scriptblock is not needed. see edit

Comment: `$f={` is redundant, `while` -> `for`, `-band1`-> `%2`, `-des`->`-d` and other golf tricks. It's clear. Can you explain how to work `$args|sort{@(1,1,...,1)}`? It's work! How the sort compares arrays without explicit `.Count`? where to read about it? Thanks!

Comment: @mazzy, you're right, I removed the redundant bits now. It's the default sorting of the Sort-Object cmdlet. See: `help Sort-Object -Parameter property` I don't know where the default sorting property for types is defined, but for arrays it is Count or Length.

Comment: Good guess. But `$args|sort{while($_){if($_-band1){$_};$_=$_-shr1}}-des` gives a wrong result. Therefore, it is not `Count`. It's very interesting. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

## ECMAScript 6, 61

Assumes `z` is the input

```
z.sort((a,b)=>{c=d=e=0;while(++c<32)d+=a>>c&1,e+=b>>c&1},e-d)
```

Test data

```
[28943,825,11746,16375,32425,19944,21826,15752,15342,3944,28436].sort(
    (a,b)=>{
        c=d=e=0;
        while(++c<32)
            d+=a>>c&1,e+=b>>c&1
    },e-d
)

[16375, 15342, 32425, 11746, 19944, 28436, 28943, 15752, 3944, 21826, 825]
```

Thanks, toothbrush for the shorter solution.

Comment: I've just tried your solution, but it didn't work. It doesn't sort the numbers.

Comment: @toothbrush woops. Thanks for catching that, should work now.

Comment: Great work! I like it.

Comment: Only 61 bytes: `z.sort((a,b)=>{c=d=e=0;while(++c<32)d+=a>>c&1,e+=b>>c&1},e-d)` (and thanks for the up-vote).

Comment: My solution is now the same size as yours!

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>132</s> <s>96</s> <s>94</s> <s>88</s> <s>84</s> <s>75</s> <s>73</s> <s>53</s> 51 bytes

-20 thanks to J.Doe's implementation
-2 more thanks to Giuseppe

```r
function(x)x[order(colSums(sapply(x,intToBits)<1))]
```

My original post:

```r
pryr::f(rev(x[order(sapply(x,function(y)sum(as.double(intToBits(y)))))]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCoAgEAXQ63whOoDLztAuWlgaCObIjIaefqq3faxaeLC1Fzg86BuxDwxxpaSBPl0tnzVSxjDSbjiZPbUjBcRcV1pilW9@uzGqLw)

I tried several different methods before I got down to this result.

**Matrix Method:** Created a two column matrix, one column with the input vector, one of the sum of the binary representation, then I sorted on the sum of binary.

```r
function(x){m=matrix(c(x,colSums(sapply(x,function(y){as.integer(intToBits(y))}))),nc=2,nr=length(x));m[order(m[,2],decreasing=T),]}
```

**Non-Matrix:** Realized I could toss out the matrix function and instead create a vector of binary values, sum them, order them, then use the ordered values to reorder the input vector.

```r
function(x){m=colSums(sapply(x,function(y){as.integer(intToBits(y))}));x[order(m,decreasing=T)]}
```

**Minor Changes**

```r
function(x){m=colSums(sapply(x,function(y)as.double(intToBits(y))));x[order(m,decreasing=T)]}
```

**More Minor Changes** Converting entire thing to one line of code instead of two separated by a semicolon.

```r
function(x)x[order(colSums(sapply(x,function(y)as.double(intToBits(y)))),decreasing=T)]
```

**Sum Method** Instead of adding the columns with `colSums` of the binary matrix created by `sapply`, I added the elements in the column before `sapply` "finished."

```r
function(x)x[order(sapply(x,function(y)sum(as.double(intToBits(y)))),decreasing=T)]
```

**Decreasing to Rev** I really wanted to shorten decreasing, but R squawks at me if I try to shorten `decreasing` in the `order` function, which was necessary to get the order desired as `order` defaults to increasing, then I remembered the `rev` function to reverse a vector. **EUREKA!!!** The last change in the final solution was `function` to `pryr::f` to save 2 more bytes

```r
function(x)rev(x[order(sapply(x,function(y)sum(as.double(intToBits(y)))))])
```

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcqxCoAgEADQva9ovIMM22vpF2qLhqgTBFPxFOzrL9fHS8KURyZ6QGNX@1n1fL3REUy6gZmVmOLvbIOHivUI6aEE6g5uKy8DXzG6D@pgfd7DajPjskyIp5jW5Qc "R – Try It Online")

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##Dcq9CoAgEADgvadwvIOK3J16hdqiIfIEwT88BXt6c/34cmcqKxNp2HBqQi2CH58cgdwGGLV0U8NbbAzQsF0xa8rwRndUz8BPSu6DNttQzrjbwqgk4t3NyP0H) improving on @J.Doe 's excellent golf!

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 123C

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
b 0=[]
b n=mod n 2:b(div n 2)
c n=(n,(sum.b)n)
q x=map fst$sortBy(comparing snd)(map c x)
```

This is the first way I thought of solving this, but I bet there's a better way to do it. Also, if anyone knows of a way of golfing Haskell imports, I would be very interested to hear it.

### Example

```
*Main> q [4,2,15,5,3]
[4,2,5,3,15]
*Main> q [7,0,2]
[0,2,7]
```

### Ungolfed version (with explanations)

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

-- Converts an integer into a list of its bits
binary 0 = []
binary n = mod n 2 : binary (div n 2)

-- Creates a tuple where the first element is the number and the second element
-- is the sum of its bits.
createTuple n = (n, (sum.binary) n)

-- 1) Turns the list x into tuples
-- 2) Sorts the list of tuples by its second element (bit sum)
-- 3) Pulls the original number out of each tuple
question x = map fst $ sortBy (comparing snd) (map createTuple x)
```

Comment: would it be helpful to use the infix notation for `mod`, ``n`mod`2``? It  has the same precedence as multiplication and division.

Comment: That wouldn't be too helpful for golfing reasons as far as I can see. I'd lose two spaces, but gain two backticks, right?

Comment: import Data.List;import Data.Ord;import Data.Bits;q=sortBy(comparing popCount) - 80C - or using your approach, import Data.List;import Data.Ord;b 0=0;b n=(mod n 2)+b(div n 2);q=sortBy(comparing b) - 86C

Comment: I tried avoiding imports entirely, best I could manage was 87C by golfing quicksort: b 0=0;b n=mod n 2+b(div n 2);q[]=[];q(a:c)=f((b a>).b)c++a:f((b a<=).b)c;f=(q.).filter

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 41 bytes

```julia
a->sort(a,by=x->sum((x>>n)&1 for n=0:63))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrdCsIgGIDh867igyAUDPJnbgs2uo/owJUuo33C1Nqu3kaH78P7ym9v@FJcN9jRI@xh9B8LBgOuU8gRXMZ78gHBAJrJggszJBuTx7GYYx/DnIhhw9otW@SJkKXvkR74f8TudNaS0mLxsbvEZ/iCI1euZV2xRlSMt61SDHgllWAghdoMOK@VZiAaJfWNlh8)

Comment: Firstly, you can use two argument sum, like this: `sum(n->x>>n&1,0:63)`. Secondly, `by=count_ones` is even shorter

Comment: Also, shorter than two argument sum is: `sum(x.>>(0:63).&1))`

Answer (score 2):

**DFSORT** (IBM Mainframe sorting product) **288** (each source line is 72 characters, must have space in position one)

```
 INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,BUILD=(1,2,1,2,TRAN=BIT)), 
       IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,FINDREP=(STARTPOS=3,INOUT=(C'0',C'')))
 SORT FIELDS=(3,16,CH,D) 
 OUTREC BUILD=(1,2)
```

Just for fun, and no mathematics.

Takes a file (could be executed from a program which used an "array") with the integers. Before sorting, it translates the integers to bits (in a 16-character field). Then changes the 0s in the bits to nothing. SORT Descending on the result of the changed bits. Creates the sorted file with just the integers.

Answer (score 2):

## Smalltalk (Smalltalk/X), 36 (or maybe 24)

input in a; destructively sorts in a:

```
a sort:[:a :b|a bitCount>b bitCount]
```

functional version: returns a new sorted array:

```
a sorted:[:a :b|a bitCount>b bitCount]
```

there is even a shorter variant (passing the *name* or the function as argument) in 24 chars.
But (sigh) it will sort highest last. As I understood, this was not asked for, so I don't take that as golf score:

```
a sortBySelector:#bitCount
```

Answer (score 2):

## CoffeeScript (94)

Readable code (212):

```
sort_by_ones_count = (numbers) ->
  numbers.sort (a, b) ->
    a1 = a.toString(2).match(/1/g).length
    b1 = b.toString(2).match(/1/g).length
    if a1 == b1
      0
    else if a1 > b1
      1
    else
      -1

console.log sort_by_ones_count [825, 3944, 11746, 15342, 15752, 16375, 19944, 21826, 28436, 28943, 32425]
```

Optimized (213):

```
count_ones = (number) -> number.toString(2).match(/1/g).length
sort_by_ones_count = (numbers) -> numbers.sort (a, b) ->
  a1 = count_ones(a)
  b1 = count_ones(b)
  if a1 == b1 then 0 else if a1 > b1 then 1 else -1
```

Obfuscating (147):

```
c = (n) -> n.toString(2).match(/1/g).length
s = (n) -> n.sort (a, b) ->
  a1 = c(a)
  b1 = c(b)
  if a1 == b1 then 0 else if a1 > b1 then 1 else -1
```

Ternary operators are excessively long (129):

```
c = (n) -> n.toString(2).match(/1/g).length
s = (n) -> n.sort (a, b) ->
  a1 = c(a)
  b1 = c(b)
  (0+(a1!=b1))*(-1)**(0+(a1>=b1))
```

Too long yet, stop casting (121):

```
c = (n) -> n.toString(2).match(/1/g).length
s = (n) -> n.sort (a, b) ->
  a1 = c(a)
  b1 = c(b)
  (-1)**(a1>=b1)*(a1!=b1)
```

Final (94):

```
c=(n)->n.toString(2).match(/1/g).length
s=(n)->n.sort((a, b)->(-1)**(c(a)>=c(b))*(c(a)!=c(b)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 58

```
def c(l:List[Int])=l.sortBy(-_.toBinaryString.count(_>48))
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP 5.4+ 131

I don't even know why I bother with PHP, in this case:

```
<?unset($argv[0]);usort($argv,function($a,$b){return strcmp(strtr(decbin($b),[0=>'']),strtr(decbin($a),[0=>'']));});print_r($argv);
```

Usage:

```
> php -f sortbybinaryones.php 15342 28943 16375 3944 11746 825 32425 28436 21826 15752 19944
Array
(
    [0] => 16375
    [1] => 15342
    [2] => 32425
    [3] => 28436
    [4] => 19944
    [5] => 11746
    [6] => 28943
    [7] => 3944
    [8] => 15752
    [9] => 825
    [10] => 21826
)
```

Comment: well, someone *has* to bother with PHP

Answer (score 2):

## C

```
void main()
{
 int a[]={7,6,15,16};
 int b,i,n=0;
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {  for(b=0,n=0;b<=sizeof(int);b++)
      (a[i]&(1<<b))?n++:n;   
    a[i]=n;
 }
 for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) 
  {   int tmp = a[i];
      for (n = i; n >= 1 && tmp < a[n-1]; n--)
         a[n] = a[n-1];
      a[n] = tmp;
  }    
}
```

Comment: Since this is a code golf competition, you should try to shorten your code.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <strike>88</strike> 89

```
int[] b(int[] a){return a.OrderBy(i=>-Convert.ToString(i,2).Count(c=>c=='1')).ToArray();}
```

Edit: descending order adds a character.

Answer (score 2):

## ECMAScript 6 (61 characters):

```
_=_=>_.toString(2).replace(/0/g,'');x.sort((a,b)=>_(b)-_(a))
```

*Expects the input array to be in `x`.*

Answer (score 2):

### **Javascript** 84

Inspired by other javascript answers, but without eval and regex.

```
var r=(x)=>(+x).toString(2).split('').reduce((p,c)=>p+ +c)
[28943,825,11746,16375,32425,19944,21826,15752,15342,3944,28436].sort((x,y)=>r(x)-r(y));
```

Comment: The question is code golf, please try to 'golf' your code: remove unnecessary whitespace and try to make your code as small as possible. Also, include a character count in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

## C - <s>124</s> 111

Implemented as a method and using the standard library for the sorting. A pointer to the array and the size should be passed as parameters. This will only work on systems with 32-bit pointers. On 64-bit systems, some characters have to be spent specifying pointer definitions.

Indentation for readability

```
c(int*a,int*b){
    int d,e,i;
    for(d=e=i=0;i-32;){
        d+=*a>>i&1;e+=*b>>i++&1;
    }
    return d>e?-1:d<e;
}
o(r,s){qsort(r,s,4,c);}
```

Sample call:

```
main() {
    static int a[] ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    o(a, 9);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript (82)

```
a.sort(function(b,c){q=0;while(b|c){b%2?c%2?0:q++:c%2?q--:0;b>>=1;c>>=1}return q})
```

Answer (score 2):

### Postscript, 126

Because list of values by which we sort is known beforehand and very limited (32), this task can be easily done even if there's no built-in for sorting, by picking matching values for 1..32. (Is it O(32n)? Probably).

Procedure expects array on stack and returns 'sorted' array.

```
/sort_by_bit_count {
    [ exch
    32 -1 1 {
        1 index
        {
            dup 2 32 string cvrs
            0 exch
            {48 sub add} forall
            2 index eq 
            {3 1 roll} {pop} ifelse
        } forall
        pop
    } for
    pop ]
} def
```

Or, ritually stripped of white space and readability:

```
/s{[exch 32 -1 1{1 index{dup 2 32 string cvrs 0 exch{48 sub add}forall 2 index eq{3 1 roll}{pop}ifelse}forall pop}for pop]}def
```

Then, if saved to `bits.ps` it can be used like this:

```
gs -q -dBATCH bits.ps -c '[(%stdin)(r)file 1000 string readline pop cvx exec] s =='
825 3944 11746 15342 15752 16375 19944 21826 28436 28943 32425
[16375 15342 32425 11746 19944 28436 28943 3944 15752 825 21826]
```

I think it effectively is the same as this Perl (there's yet no Perl here, too):

```
sub f{map{$i=$_;grep{$i==(()=(sprintf'%b',$_)=~/1/g)}@_}reverse 1..32}
```

Though *that*, unlike Postscript, can be easily golfed:

```
sub f{sort{j($b)-j($a)}@_}sub j{$_=sprintf'%b',@_;()=/1/g}
```

Comment: Postscript! My first love, my favorite language of all time! It is nice to see another believer in the One True Programming Language.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8: 144

```java
static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(Stream.of(a).mapToInt(Integer::decode).sorted(Comparable.comparing(Integer::bitCount)).toArray());}
```

In expanded form:

```java
static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.print(
        Stream.of(args).mapToInt(Integer::decode)
              .sorted(Comparable.comparing(Integer::bitCount))
              .toArray()
        );
}
```

As you can see, this works by converting the `args` to a `Stream<String>`, then converting to a `Stream<Integer>` with the `Integer::decode` function reference (shorter than `parseInt` or `valueOf`), and then sorting by `Integer::bitCount`, then putting it in an array, and printing it out.

Streams make everything easier.

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell v2 or later, 44

```
sort{[convert]::ToString($_,2)-replace0}-des
```

The long version:

```
Sort-Object -Property {[convert]::ToString($_, 2) -replace '0', ''} -Descending
```

"sort" is a default alias for the Sort-Object cmdlet.
Sort-Object allows sorting the incoming list by evaluating an expression on the fly, which is the script block inside the curly braces.
The .NET class "Convert" is used to convert the incoming integer ("$_") into its binary string representation.
The "-replace" Operator will then remove all zeros, so that only a string of ones remains (the string "Replace()" method would have worked, too, but would have been longer).
Since these strings all consist of the same character, they'll be sorted by length, ascending by default. The switch argument "Descending" will reverse the order, and since there's another argument 'Debug', the first three characters are required for PowerShell to identify the switch.

The list to sort is expected in the pipeline/stdin, for example:

```
$l = 15342, 28943, 16375, 3944, 11746, 825, 32425, 28436, 21826, 15752, 19944
$l | sort{[convert]::ToString($_,2)-replace0}-des
```

Sort-Object
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6

Convert Class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: It's a code snippet, not function or program. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ΣbSO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OKkYP///6MNdYx0jHVMdEx1zHTMdSx0LHUMDWIB)

Comment: 4-byte alternative which is a literal translation of the title: `Σb1¢` (`Σ`ort numbers by `b`inary `1`s `¢`ount) :) (Bit of a weird `s` in `sort` though.. ;p)

Comment: I don't think this is in descending order.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 27 bytes

```perl6
*.sort(-*.base(2).comb.sum)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpNDoMgEEDhvadgZcBMSeaHAWJ6GG10JdFIu/D0VLfve8dybtrKZfrVvNvg635@7Wvw81QXS85/9jL7@iuujV2dLrNai8oxQKIAnEUAQwwEhIkUKGVhwPx0SsJ6KwsBk9w7YhR1rv0B)

Comment: Alternatively, `.comb(~1)`

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>191</s> <s>183</s> 172 thanks to [Rik](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/13778/rik)

```c#
 using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",a.Select(int.Parse).OrderBy(v=>{int c=0;for(;v>0;c++,v&=v-1);return-c;})));}}
```

Formatted:

```c#
using System.Linq;
class P
{
    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", a.Select(int.Parse)
            .OrderBy(v => { 
                int c = 0; 
                for (; v > 0; c++, v &= v - 1);
                return -c; 
            })
        ));
    }
}
```

When run as `foo.exe 32425 28943 28436 21826 19944 16375 15752 15342 11746  3944 825` the output is:

```c#
16375 15342 32425 28943 28436 19944 11746 15752 3944 21826 825
```

Including the bitcount:

```c#
16375   13
15342   11
32425   10
28943   8
28436   8
19944   8
11746   8
15752   7
3944    7
21826   6
825     5
```

## As function only: <s>100</s> 89 chars

...Which some seem to regard as correct too:

```c#
int[] v(int[]a){return a.OrderBy(v=>{int c=0;for(;v>0;c++,v&=v-1);return-c;}).ToArray();}
```

To use, call `v()` with an array of ints to be sorted by binary 1's count.

Comment: instead of `OrderByDescending` you can use `OrderBy` and `return -c` in your lambda and save 9 chars.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks! Why didn't I think of that?! :D Actually, it saves 10 since I don't need a space between `return` and `-c` :D

Answer (score 1):

## C++ and QT

```
template<typename T>

//Compars the number of ones in the binary representation of some numbers 
bool onesCountSort()(Const T* a, const T* b) const
{
   int aCount = getOnesCount(&a);
   int bCount = getOnesCount(&b);
   return aCount < bCount;
}

//Returns the number of ones in a number
int getOnesCount(T value) const
{
    int rVal = 0;
    while(value > 0)
    {
       rVal++;
       value = value >> 1;
    } 
    return rVal;
}    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QList<int> listTest;
   listTest << 16375;
   listTest << 15342; 
   listTest << 32425; 
   listTest << 11746; 
   listTest << 28436;
   //...

   qSort(list.begin(); list.end(), onesCountSort<int>());//Sort by binary ones count
   qSort(list.end(); list.begin(), onesCountSort<int>());//Reverse the sort
}
```

### Edit:

```
template<typename T>

//Compars the number of ones in the binary representation of some numbers 
bool onesCountSort()(Const T* a, const T* b) const
{
   return getOnesCount(a) < getOnesCount(b);
}

int getOnesCount(const T* value, int count = 0) const
{
    return &value ? count : getOnesCount(value >> 1, count + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### GolfScript, 14 chars

```
~{2base 0-,}$`
```

Example input (sorted in numerical order):

```
[825 3944 11746 15342 15752 16375 19944 21826 28436 28943 32425]
```

Example output (sorted by bit count) for the input above:

```
[825 21826 15752 3944 28436 28943 19944 11746 32425 15342 16375]
```

Note that the program above sorts the input in ascending order by bit count.  If you insist on descending order, that'll cost one extra char:

```
~{2base 0-,~}$`
```

**Explanation:**

- `~` evals the input. Since you didn't specify the input format, I took the liberty of assuming that the input is provided as a GolfScript array literal (i.e. a series of whitespace-separated numbers wrapped in `[ ]`).
- `{ }$` applies the code inside the braces to each element of the array, and sorts them according to the resulting sort keys.

  - Inside the braces, `2base` uses the built-in base conversion operator to turn the number into an array of bits (e.g. `19` → `[1 0 0 1 1]`). The `0-` then removes all the zero bits from the array (the space before it is needed to keep `base0` from being parsed as a single token) and the `,` counts the length of the remaining array.
  - (In the descending order version, the `~` then bitwise negates the count, effectively applying the map *x* ↦ −(*x* + 1) and thus inverting the sort order.)
- Finally, the `` ` `` un-evals the sorted array, converting it back into the input format for output.

Answer (score 1):

**

### C++(Visual Studio 2013), 112

**

```
#define n int
#define s __popcnt
n* d(n i[], n l){sort(i, i+l, [](n a, n b){return  s(a) > s(b); });return i;}
```

Unobfuscated:

```
#define n int
#define s __popcnt
n* d(n i[], n l){
    std::sort(i, i+l, [](n a, n b){return  s(a) > s(b); });
    return i;
}
```

haven't touched C++ for a while. While not the shortest, it PROBABLY is the fastest, by far, though it depends highly if the __popcnt is implemented as single CPU instruction, or set.

I might fire up mathbrain later and see if it's possible to compare two numbers by bits and see which one has more bits set(without any string conversions or bit counting). I think there is some kind of bit-hack that can be used, but it's probably longer.

Answer (score 1):

**C : 112**

```
C(a){int c=a!=0;while(a&=a-1)c++;return c;}
B(int*a,int*b){return C(*b)-C(*a);}
S(int*a,int n){qsort(a,n,4,B);}
```

works on gcc with `Target: x86_64-linux-gnu`

usage: `S(array, size);`

Comment: similar to @albeert's answer, which I only saw after I completed this...

Comment: `S(n,int*a)` doesn't compile. Even when fixed, doesn't work on by 64bit Linux with gcc. Omitting `return` from `C` is very fragile.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I missed the compiler error among the warnings and got the same output as the previous run, so I assumed it was good. I went back to my last working version: +12 char.

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY1NDoIwFIT3PQVpYtLKI@FHEVK5gTuXwuJZKWlU0MKCSHp1a1m4mUwm883IqJPSuTND6Lnupy2K5T0OZloD2MGJ1nN@LWKlsnpWfyMzWaQl5cK6J@qe8YV4NkCDl6ZaEkgh8@wecjhAASUksRXEfxj0lguiBsNWQFex0MfESxj6jZfxoWJ0cwsorGO68WVLrPtK9cBudNGnnVs5TijvPw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

**Haskell - <strike>107</strike>100 (including sample list and main call) else 100-22=78**

```
import Data.List
b 0=0
b n=mod n 2+b(div n 2)
c q=map snd$ sort$ zip(map b q)q
main=print$ c [1..100]
```

Result:

```
[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,3,5,6,9,10,12,17,18,20,24,33,34,36,40,48,65,66,68,72,80,96,7,11,13,14,19,21,22,25,26,28,35,37,38,41,42,44,49,50,52,56,67,69,70,73,74,76,81,82,84,88,97,98,100,15,23,27,29,30,39,43,45,46,51,53,54,57,58,60,71,75,77,78,83,85,86,89,90,92,99,31,47,55,59,61,62,79,87,91,93,94,63,95]
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, 95 chars

Call `s(array, size)` to sort an array.
The framework is based on [AShelly's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21492/3544), with a different bit count function.
Only works on 32bit platforms.

```
c(unsigned a){return a?a%2+c(a/2):0;}
f(int*a,int*b){return c(*b)-c(*a);}
s(a,n){qsort(a,n,4,f);}
```

The bit count function treats the numbers as unsigned, so division will discard the low bit.

Answer (score 1):

## php 5.3, <strike>117</strike> 109

Thank to @mniip to point out some more char save. So New One are

```
usort($a,function($u,$v){return $u==$v?0:(substr_count(decbin($u),'1')<substr_count(decbin($v),'1')?1:-1);});
```

Older One

```
usort($a,function($u,$v){if($u==$v)return 0;return substr_count(decbin($u),'1')<substr_count(decbin($v),'1')?1:-1;});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can save a few chars if you combine your return statements into one using ternary operator

Answer (score 1):

## K, 14

```
{x@>+/'0b\:'x}
```

.

```
k){x@>+/'0b\:'x} 28943 16375 15342
16375 15342 28943
```

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript (ECMAScript 6) - 41 Characters**

Takes an array `a` as input:

```
a.sort(ພ=(ຟ,ຝ)=>ຟ*ຝ?ພ(ຟ&ຟ-1,ຝ&ຝ-1):(ຝ-ຟ))
```

Testing (with less obfuscated code):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/38FLY/)

```
a=[19944, 11746, 15342, 21826, 825, 28943, 32425, 16375, 28436, 3944, 15752];
a.sort(_=(b,c)=>b*c?_(b&b-1,c&c-1):(c-b))
console.log(a.toString());
```

Gives this output:

```
16375,15342,32425,19944,11746,28943,28436,3944,15752,21826,825
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# - 98

C# can't really compete in "the smallest" category. Still fun, though :)

```
x.Select(i=>new{v=i,c=Convert.ToString(i,2).Count(c=>c=='1')}).OrderByDescending(a=>a.c);
```

Used:

```
var y = new [] {28943, 825, 11746, 16375, 32425, 19944, 21826, 15752, 15342, 3944, 28436}.Select(i=>new{v=i,c=Convert.ToString(i,2).Count(c=>c=='1')}).OrderByDescending(a=>a.c);
Console.WriteLine(y.Select(a => a.v.ToString()).Aggregate((s1,s2)=>s1+","+s2));
```

Result:

```
16375,15342,32425,28943,11746,19944,28436,15752,3944,825,21826
```

EDIT: .NetFiddle - http://dotnetfiddle.net/ahMMbq

Answer (score 1):

Longwinded C#:

```cs
using System;

namespace P
{
    class P
    {
        static int T(int v) { int i = 0; while (v != 0) { i += (v & 1); v >>= 1; } return i; }
        static int[] S(int[] a)
        { Array.Sort<int>(a, (x, y) => { return (T(x) > T(y)) ? -1 : (T(x) < T(y)) ? 0 : 1; }); return a; }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var i in S(new int[]{ 28943, 825, 11746, 16375, 32425, 19944, 21826, 15752, 15342, 3944, 28436 }))
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", i, Convert.ToString(i, 2), T(i));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**C# 95**

```
int[]o(int[]d){return d.OrderByDescending(v =>Convert.ToString(v,2).Sum(c =>c-'0')).ToArray();}
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP - 89 bytes

Here is the best I have been able to do so far.

```
function f($a){usort($a,function($a,$b){$c=gmp_popcount;return$c($a)<$c($b);});return$a;}
```

If I am allowed to sort the array in-place (which is idiomatic for PHP), then it is only 81:

```
function f(&$a){usort($a,function($a,$b){$c=gmp_popcount;return$c($a)<$c($b);});}
```

Comment: requires `gmp` library, which is neither in the default built nor activated by default. (see http://php.net/manual/gmp.installation.php)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 56 bytes

```perl
sub x{$_=sprintf'%b',@_;s/1//g}print sort{x($b)<=>x$a}<>
```

Input is expected in STDIN, one integer per line. Output is in descending order.

`sprintf '%b'` converts the number into binary representation. `s/1//` replaces the `1`, the return value is the number of replacements. Thus function `x` returns the number of `1` in the binary representation of the number. The sorting function sorts the number according to their binary 1's count. By exchanging `$a` and `$b` the sorting order is reversed to ascending.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 7 bytes

```
ñ_¤è1Ãw
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8V+k6DHDdw==&input=WzgyNSwzOTQ0LDExNzQ2LDE1MzQyLDE1NzUyLDE2Mzc1LDE5OTQ0LDIxODI2LDI4NDM2LDI4OTQzLDMyNDI1XQ==)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of array `U`.

```
ñ_   Ã
```

Sort (`ñ`) by passing each element through a function.

```
¤
```

Convert to base 2 string.

```
è1
```

Count the number of `1`s.

```
w
```

Reverse and implicitly output the resulting array.

---

### Alternatives

```
ñ_¤o1Ãw
ñ_¤kTÃw
```

Comment: You need descending sort, not ascending.

Comment: Another alternative I believe would be `ñ_¤è1 n`. Don't think that'd be shorter combined with the other alternative, but you never know...

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript**
- Lengthy but result is according to my expectation
- sorting numbers in ascending order according to number of binary 1s in them. If binary 1s are equal then sorting done on the base of decimal ascending order.

**Thumbs up if anybody can improve or give shorter solution in javascript**

```
  function sortNumberByBinary1s(numbers){
      //sort numbers first
      numbers=numbers.sort();
      console.log(numbers,'numbers');

      //2dimenstional array to store original number and its binary 1s
      var binNumArr = [];
      //loop to count binary 1s in each number
      for(i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
        var num = numbers[i];
        // var binNum = Number(num.toString(2));

        let binary1 = 0;
        do if(num&1) binary1++;
        while(num>>=1);

        //store original number and its binary 1s in 2dimenstional array
        binNumArr[numbers[i]]={'number':numbers[i],'binary1':binary1};

      }

    //sort binNumArr (22dimenstional array by Number value)
    //filter(() => true) to remove empty values
      var byNumSortedArray=binNumArr.sort(function(a, b){return a.number - b.number}).filter(() => true);

      //sort byNumberSorted array by binary1 value
      var byBinary1SortedArray=byNumSortedArray.sort(function(a, b){return a.binary1 - b.binary1});

      console.log(byBinary1SortedArray,'byBinary1SortedArray');

    //get only sortedNumbers from array and return result
      var sortedNumbers=[]
      for(i=0;i<byBinary1SortedArray.length;i++){
        try{
          var number = byBinary1SortedArray[i].number;
        }catch(e){
          console.log(e,'error');
        }
        console.log(number,'number');
        sortedNumbers[i]=number;

      }
      console.log(sortedNumbers,'sortedNumbers array');
      return sortedNumbers;

    }
```

**Input: [3,4,5,6,7,8]**

```
  sortNumberByBinary1s([3,4,5,6,7,8]);
```

- {number: 4, binary1: 1}
- {number: 8, binary1: 1}
- {number: 3, binary1: 2}
- {number: 5, binary1: 2}
- {number: 6, binary1: 2}
- {number: 7, binary1: 3}

**Output: [4, 8, 3, 5, 6, 7]**

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a code golf challenge, so you should aim to minimise your code as much as possible, starting with removing all comments and changing variable names to a single letter

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 bytes

```
╖a☻║B⌡
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b76102ba42f5&i=[16375,+15342,+32425,+11746,+28436,+19944,+28943,+3944,+15752,+825,+21826]%0A%0A[21826,+825,+15752,+3944,+28943,+19944,+28436,+11746,+32425,+15342,+16375]%0A%0A[28436,+21826,+15342,+19944,+15752,+28943,+16375,+825,+3944,+32425,+11746]%0A%0A[32425,+28943,+3944,+11746,+21826,+15752,+825,+28436,+15342,+19944,+16375]%0A%0A[16375,+32425,+11746,+15752,+19944,+15342,+21826,+825,+28943,+28436,+3944]%0A%0A[3,4,5,6,7,8]&a=1&m=1)

This will output the Unicode characters in a string. Add `$` at the end (or step through execution) to see decimal.

### Unpacked (7 bytes) and Explanation

```
{:B|+or
{          Begin block.
 :B          Convert to binary array. Ex: 11746 -> [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
   |+        Sum.
     o     Terminate block and use it to sort array (ascending).
      r    Reverse. Implicit print.
```

Before descending order was specified in the question, there was a 6-byte unpacked solution. This is short enough that packing (into `ÇÄì¬♥#`) changed nothing:

```
{:B|+o
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7B%3AB%7C%2Bo&i=[16375,+15342,+32425,+11746,+28436,+19944,+28943,+3944,+15752,+825,+21826]%0A%0A[21826,+825,+15752,+3944,+28943,+19944,+28436,+11746,+32425,+15342,+16375]%0A%0A[28436,+21826,+15342,+19944,+15752,+28943,+16375,+825,+3944,+32425,+11746]%0A%0A[32425,+28943,+3944,+11746,+21826,+15752,+825,+28436,+15342,+19944,+16375]%0A%0A[16375,+32425,+11746,+15752,+19944,+15342,+21826,+825,+28943,+28436,+3944]%0A%0A[3,4,5,6,7,8]&a=1&m=1)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>57</s> 54 bytes

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni?tab=profile)! (making the counting function pointfree by using the fact that we only need to support 32bit ints)</sup>

```hs
sortOn$sum.(mapM(pure[0,1])[1..32]!!)
import Data.List
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcq9DoIwFEDh3ae4RgdILg0Ffwm46GKicXBEhgYKNkJp2svrW3E5w5fzFu4j@96vGtkqLcHBy7vR0kOv3TSwYBDmHpjJyjJGXoUlZyxNquUyXKjBzB9cBAl2U478IJSGAoxVmoBB4MJ/rRQNZBk8afYOohOUV01VCEWeQyfpPGqSmpwvOSaY4ga3uMM9HvCIPK6@dduLzvmoNuYH)

### Explanation

The function call `sortOn f xs` returns `xs :: [x]` sorted by comparing `ys = map (f :: x -> y) xs` where the type `y` has to be an instance of `Ord`, so we just need to feed it a function that counts the number of 1-bits:

```hs
(sum . mapM (const [0,1]) [1..32] !!)
```

The expression `mapM (const [0,1]) [1..n]` generates all the sequences of `[0,1]` with length `n` (`n = 32` is sufficient since we only need to handle 32bit ints) in the right order, so we just need to index into these and take it's sum.

Example: `mapM (const [0,1]) [1..2] !! 1 ≡ [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]] !! 2 ≡ [0,1]`

Comment: As the challenge only requires 32-bit integers, this could be shortened to `sortOn$sum.(mapM(pure[0,1])[1..32]!!)` while losing higher number support. Btw. nice workaround with `#define` on TIO.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>57</s> 44 bytes

```
{it.sortedBy{-it.toString(2).sumBy{it-'0'}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7NCoMwEITvfYq9NYJKTWL9QYX2Vij00CcQWiVUY4lrQcRntxsF9zLsl9mZfDpslF5@ZQNVCuyuesxuGgsHvAL2DfJlUuj3ncH36zpOHi3YPdEoXTPu@P3QElXoHU/HeZ6XatDQlkqz0tR9ChdjyjHb7JQ8HYDGVjZUAPkqj4oFSSKlC0EQyTNJKCR3gceJFCRBzC08iyi0UIrVEoVkiTkhsd4KLnno7PndYOMrZgs2@qU/YKMZvTiHefkD)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
{x@>+/2\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCoAwDEbhq2QXkfxJk9ZBPIhzHYTOBfHsMcs3PN6zjntE9P2d57FsuOYXnZhdjSoKsYmnxQtSURC4wkiaKgk0F1QVS5sKccsePw)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 5 bytes

```
á{âΣ~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxDYAwDAXRhdz4206cWRAFDVCAaOiQ2AUYJT0rmdDeu3XY52lbxoh6HfV@nzOi4yTZyGEkRZXYsoHAjkTwokJc/g5XSU1FQQJtO3PW1H8)

#### Explanation:

```
á{âΣ~
á{     Sort by the
    ~  Negative
   Σ   Digit sum
  â    Of the number converted to binary
```

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, <s>40</s> 45 bytes

```powershell
$args|sort{for(;$_;$_=$_-shr1){$s+=$_%2}$s}-d
```

Explanation:

Sort all arguments from the predefined `$args` in a descendant order by sum of bits `$s`.

Note: The script uses `-shr1` instead `/2` because a Powershell does not provide integer `div`.

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

$args|sort{for(;$_;$_=$_-shr1){$s+=$_%2}$s}-d

}

&$f 0 1 3 4
&$f 16375 15342 32425 11746 28436 19944 28943 3944 15752 825 21826
```

Output:

```powershell
3
0
4
1
16375
15342
32425
19944
28943
11746
28436
15752
3944
21826
825
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 31 bytes

```
[ [ bit-count ] inv-sort-with ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BDoIwDEDv@4r@ACR0BYZ@gPHixXgiHJBMWYRBRpUY47dPdNjTS5vXvEvd8OD86bg/7DZw087qDvqa2/hseDaThtFp5ufojGWYBsfGXmErxEvAMklREAVKJWGgJKfsRwrTsMlkHggVyXDDRGG2mnkaTIm0GvL/FlVBUryFL6GEJSlqhvsSUoGxj@ibE82GW6h8U3cdxP4D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```rust
|s|s.sort_by_key(|n|n.count_zeros())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5LCoMwGIT3nsK6KAkEIS@fSA8iIm0xINVfSeLCqmdPY0s3wzB8M4xejHUKwvHeA8Lb0NlQFQrQdVxsWPecNbhyu9lNbCZt28favroV7bBD/JwWsO2705NBGLsyOMtnrYfZaxXWNOGpJJwJJgnLcsEJz4UgVKaSkewMacYSQmkqEg8I7n3uiaYM1O/BdwqXwax7sANcULQVtyMi//xwHw)

Modifies the input slice in place. It works by sorting the array by the number of zeros. Another 36 byte solution:

```rust
|s|s.sort_by_key(|n|!n.count_ones())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5LCoMwGIT3niK6KAkEIQ/fSA8iIm0xEKq/YuJCjGdPtaWbYRi@GWZZjfUK0PjQgMk@9BapUgG@jatFjRa8JbV3xpnYTIvtnlv37jfswIUQv6YVbDdBbzAhvgqu8lXTMJ9ao4alIkuo4JInlOeFFFQUUlKWZAmn@RWynKeUsUymJyDF6YuTaKtA/R58p0gVzIsGO0CIo728HxH954f/AA)

This one sorts by the bitwise negation of the number of ones.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
o_/.BsN"1"cw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcq5DYAwEETRVkYuADR7@EgpgBYckJCBBBKi@gUnXy/453vvEUefp@VaE9P2RNDVBGzNDComDmGVjPqLLJYh1XS0mYJZi0PHTC8u@AA)

explanation:

```
               print(
o                sorted(
           w       input()
          c        .split()
                 , key = lambda N:
 _                 -
   .B              bin(
     s               int(
      N                N
                     )
                   )
  /                .count(
       "1"           "1"
                   )
                 )
               )
```

i'm aware there already is a Pyth answer, i just wanted to take a crack at it myself

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
µb∑⌐
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCtWLiiJHijJAiLCIiLCJbMTUzNDIsMjg5NDMsMTYzNzUsMzk0NCwxMTc0Niw4MjUsMzI0MjUsMjg0MzYsMjE4MjYsMTU3NTIsMTk5NDRdIl0=)

#### Explained

```
µb∑⌐
µ     # lambda
 b    # binary
  ∑   # sum (basically adds everything inside the binary, which is equivalent to the number of 1's
   ⌐  # reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 72 bytes

```sh
(for i;<<<${#${(M)${(s::)$((i<0?[##2]2**32+i:[##2]i))}#1}}\ $i)|sort -rn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBDsIgEIXhvaeYBBZQ06TMDNBWEk/gCdSVsSkbm7SurJwdwc335s98tjlPSu9ZTcsK8RRCkLuQu7rowjaOWioVQ3e@CoF3bBrCYxz/EbVOwqR0Axn1d1vWN7TrKz8f85IOExhAIOB6IYFj6KCt5cGYMj1aoIG5lGcHxhJj0duiI2/BDPWLpkcH2DNVByYgZLT5Bw)

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea zsh could do this.

Comment: This solution also does two's complement arithmetic to handle negative integers. Most other solutions don't handle `-4` correctly!!! (But this challenge is too old to make too much fuss about it)

Comment: Never too old to make a fuss :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Þḃ1c
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWyw_Pe7ij2TB5SXFScjFUbMG2aEMdIx1jHRMdUx0zHXMdCx1LHUODWIgsAA)

**Alternatively:**

```
Þ2BS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWSw_PM3IKXlKclFwMFVmwLdpQx0jHWMdEx1THTMdcx0LHUsfQIBYiCwA)

##### Explanation

```python
Þḃ1c  # Implicit input
Þ     # Sort the input by the following:
 ḃ    #  Convert the number to binary
  1c  #  Count the number of 1s
      # Implicit output
```

```python
Þ2BS  # Implicit input
Þ     # Sort the input by the following:
 2B   #  Convert the number to a binary list
   S  #  Sum the resulting list
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
BS$ÞṚ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98pWOXwvIc7Z/3//z/a0MzY3FRHwdDU2MRIR8HYyMQIxDM0NzHTUTCyMDEGUoaWliYmIJ6liTFQCZhjaGpuClRvAVJtZGhhZBYLAA)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 71

```
usort($a,function($a,$b){for(;$a&&$b;$a&=$a-1,$b&=$b-1);return$b-$a;});
```

If we assume there will be no dulicates, 69

```
foreach($a as$v)$b[$v]=gmp_popcount($v);arsort($b);$a=array_keys($b);
```

If we accept ascending sort, 68

```
foreach($a as$v)$b[$v]=gmp_popcount($v);asort($b);$a=array_keys($b);
```

That is, given `$a`. So, I'm unclear on whether we can assume the input, as various solutions go to various lengths to get it.

Comment: Actually, you´d habe to use `$argv` and `print_r` the result or add the 23 bytes function overhead: `function($a){return$a;}`. `gmp` is not in the default config and actually you´d had to add the bytecount of installation or at least the necessary config line. Nice ones nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 51 bytes

```perl
sub j{(sprintf'%b',@_)=~y/1//}say sort{j($b)-j$a}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcnRCoIwFADQ932FD4YKmd67e@eEin6gbwgHBQ7RsdmDiH16y17Oy3FPP3CM4W0Su@bB@X6cX9nBZMfbo7h8lgqqagvdkoTJz6vNU1OUNu228zVGiYQsULckd0kqgaBRCWhbIgFKNiyAG8ZdSbvQkEqE/K9G/k5u7qcxxPLOpxrqHw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
_osjN2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcmxEYBACATAhkg4Dh6asAVTx0RnNLF6/E822ft7j@79es4N3QkXK1JUB0PUjZgOn4YNF6210EQIkrYsmhgI/wE)

###### Explanation

```
_osjN2  | Full code
_osjN2Q | with implicit variables
--------+------------------------
 o    Q | Sort the input by
   jN2  |  convert to binary list
  s     |  sum
_       | Reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
def f(l):l.sort(key=lambda x:`bin(x)`.count('1'),reverse=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI0fTKkevOL@oRCM7tdI2JzE3KSVRocIqISkzT6NCM0EvOb80r0RD3VBdU6cotSy1qDjV1lDz/38A)

Comment: Save 7 bytes by replacing `reverse=1` with `*-1` to get descending order.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3NCoMwEITP9Sn2ZlJSIZuNf@CTlIJaDZVqIqmCPn0aLx/MDDOzntvHWQxhGA0YNvN6zn7Ob@w7ns3cLf3QwVG3/WTZwdvs7Xa7sVSm/P6QPHTeQwPPErUAVREJKQvKhdSKMLLQkbkqtJDVlaIsMRdYkrpYkRIKKXZfiWFxiifGebD7ApOFqOvktvop/kWLhz8 "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 19 bytes

```
ĐĐ↑Ḷ⌊⁺ᴇĐ3ȘĦ*⇹↔+Ş⇹%Ɩ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIQjEx61TXy4Y9ujnq5Hjbsebmk/MsH4xIwjy7Qete981DZF@@g8IEP12LT//6MNzYzNTXUsjEx1jC1NTHQMTc1NjXSMDC2MzHSMLCxNjHUMLUHiRhYmxmZAWWMTIx1jIxOgckNDcxOzWAA)

#### Explanation

```
                         Implicit input (as a list of integers)
ĐĐ                       Triplicate the list
  ↑                      Get the maximum value of the list (X_m)
   Ḷ⌊⁺ᴇĐ                 Push Y=10^(floor(log_10(X_m))+1) twice
        3Ș               Swap the top three elements on the list [puts the input on top]
          Ħ              Get the Hamming weight of each element of the input
           *             Multiply the Hamming weight by Y
            ⇹            Swap the top two elements on the stack
             ↔           Flip the stack [Puts the list on top, followed by Hamming weights multiplied by Y]
              +          Add the two lists element-wise [resulting in Z=[Z_0,Z_1,...]]
               Ş         Sort the resulting list in descending order
                ⇹        Swap the top two elements on the stack
                 %       Take Z mod Y
                  Ɩ      Convert Z mod Y to integers
                         Implicit print
```

This is as long as it is because Pyt doesn't allow sorting by anything other than the values in the array; this means that a workaround had to be devised to allow the proper sorting

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 19 bytes

```
{t@>+/'(99#2)\'t:x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qusTBTltfXcPSUtlIM0a9xKqi9n@agrGJqYKhkbGCmamJgqGZsTmQZ2psYqRgbGRiZPofAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), <s>102</s> <s>99</s> 84 bytes

```
F(a)=>'1'.allMatches(a.toRadixString(2)).length;f(List l)=>l.sort((a,b)=>F(a)-F(b));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY4xC8IwEIV3f0W2XiAGcklsperopIuO4pBatYGYSnuDIP72mujy3vfg3uNaN9A0bcHx9aZQhXQh7B1duusITlJ/cK1/HWnw8Q7IuQzXeKeuvsHOj8RCKgU59gMBONGklIfmW2g4r6eH8xH4e8ZYPl75SBsW2Jqd9NIYUaEVqCpcCLXMGSujE6vSJF3o0gpltfkrCo0GM5cWz3VavEHg2Z/pM/rxZ/oC)

-3 bytes by using allMatches instead of replaceAll

-15 bytes by using - instead of compareTo and replacing List< int > by List

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 36 bytes

```perl6
@a.sort({sum .base(2).comb}).reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcnRCoMgFADQX/FhULHLBa9X041BfzJsyBgkhbpBRN/u6uW8nCWkydS4isGLh3iHgnmZPqVtoOkw@uUmtuvlud9F9msdPOY5lXbL3yhw9Dm01OFrjuPeYQq/kHKo1ZIG5ZhByp4NSK2YDnt9aFSvQbpzSVoyQJbVqWMFipj0Hw)

Comment: Taking input through a predefined variable is not allowed as it turns the submission into a snippet. Turning it into an anonymous code block is valid and the same length anyway

Comment: Some golfing tips: It's always shorter to use `[R,]` instead of `reverse`, though in this case, you can sprt be the negative of the sum instead. The `sum` can go on the end instead, like `.sum` and then you can turn it into an anonymous Whatever code object like `-*.base(2).comb.sum`. Of course, all this would make it a duplicate of [nwellnhof's existing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174996/76162) though don't let this discourage you! It's nice to see a new Perl 6 golfer!

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 27 chars, 54 bytes

```
{⍵[⍒{+/(2⍴⍨⌊1+2⍟1+⍵)⊤⍵}¨⍵]}
```

test

```
  f←{⍵[⍒{+/(2⍴⍨⌊1+2⍟1+⍵)⊤⍵}¨⍵]}
  f 825 32425 15342 11746 28943 28436 21826 16375 15752 19944 3944
16375 15342 32425 11746 28943 28436 19944 15752 3944 825 21826
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 33 bytes

```ruby
:sort_by+(:%&"%b"|~:count&?1|:-@)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWNxWtivOLSuKTKrU1rFTVlFSTlGrqrJLzS_NK1OwNa6x0HTShCucXKLhFRxtZWJoY6yhYGJnqKBgampuYASkzY3Mgz9jIBCxoaWlioqNgZGhhBJIzNTc1AlHGJkDKGCJlYWJsFhvLpaxga6cQDdUNUwE1BGIyWCWIAtsJNRlqpDGyNUDnxEKcuWABhAYA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 16 bytes

```
ĐĦ⇹Đ↑⁺Đ3Ș⇹↔*+Ş⇹%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYurDYAwFEWnwcAz79fPLIQdEBgkBmxJECgkO4AuCXN0kVLcPSfn9uOQcwzxTMsVQ5rXNN0x8LsXTvNWN89RVpVzy14EHCkQOjKAapWAnBcGRCvFGLYKTFIaVBYC9P@HnLDpPg)

Pyt only allows for sorting on the values themselves, so a kludge had to be done.

```
Đ                     implicit input (v); Đuplicate
 Ħ                    get Ħamming weight of each element (H)
  ⇹Đ↑                 get maximum of input (m)
     ⁺                increment m
      Đ               Đuplicate m
       3Ș⇹↔           Stack manipulation
           *          multiply H by m+1
            +         Add v to H*(m+1)
             Ş        Şort in descending order
              ⇹%      modulo m+1; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 14 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 11.52 bytes

```
DebdiSEZZz;.AK
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbrXFKTUjKDXaOiqqz1HL0hglC5BduiDXWMdIx1THRMdcx0zHUsdCx1DA1iIbIA)

Unfortunately Thunno lacks a "sort by" built-in.

##### Explanation

```python
DebdiSEZZz;.AK  # Implicit input
De    E         # Duplicate and map:
  bd            #  Convert to binary
    iS          #  And sum the digits
       ZZ       # Zip with input
         z;     # Reverse-sort
           .AK  # Last element of each
                # Implicit output
```